# What algorithm can I use in order to not let there be two rows with same "mobile number" in database?

Tags: algorithms, concurrency, distributed-system, distributed-development

The issue that I'm facing is on a banking app. There are two ways to register for internet banking.

**A) Self Register**
**B) Ask for bank to register via their GUI panel backend.**

Consider this scenario:

1. Say a customer is already registered MANUALLY (via bank).
2. Then he requests to change his mobile number to something else. Say A to B.
3. Then this goes to the process of "request for approval".
4. Before it got approved, that same user also did self-registration using B.
5. Later it gets approved.

Obviously, in a naive application, this too succeeds.

Later the manual approval too succeeds from GUI from bank staffs.

Now, we get two customers with same mobile number. I don't know how fatal is this, but this is completely dirty data.

For years, we just deleted that data :). Now, we want a permanent fix.

I've been thinking of couple of ideas, but I want to hear more about your ideas.

---

One of my idea is this.

Currently while self registering, we're only checking "if the customer mobile number is already registered". As I said above, we already have state machines for the status of customer. Say the customer is in request_for_approval state, then don't allow him to self register.

Please tell me a failure condition for the scenario that I'm generating(for my idea), so that I can think of other ideas.

Comment: A unique index, or have you decided SQL was not cool enough?

Comment: You know, over a span of time time, it isn't actually impossible that two customers could register with the same mobile number, as telephone numbers can be redistributed (not just by the telephone authorities as numbers lapse from use, but also amongst friends and family).

Comment: @Steve true, also some people have the nerve to not be perfect and register typos. Just because you've had this phone number since the 60s doesn't mean you typed it here first.

Comment: There's also busy people who don't want the bank calling their mobile number and so will give you their spouces number who screens their calls. A son who is caring for Grandma who doesn't answer the phone anymore. And people who aren't as well off as you who have to share a phone. Don't call it dirty just because it doesn't fit your preconceived notions.

Comment: @candied_orange, agreed. I think general opinion is that it's a recipe for disaster to enforce uniqueness at entry-time. By all means things can be flagged for further attention and questioning, but phone numbers are best regarded as like property addresses - they are not one-to-one with individuals or stable over time. Even email addresses can be shared or change hands.

Comment: @steve exactly. The best practice is to ask. A phone number is not an identity. So before you assume you have a unique identifier ask if it is ok to use it as such. Then remember people are idiots and check for correctness.

Comment: I don't understand why everyone is so upset about this requirement. Many banking systems work on the assumption that everyone has an unique phone not shared with someone else. And according to statistics, this is correct. Only the poorest of the poor don't have their own phone and those people are unlikely to be using a bank. If you have a home banking app on your phone, it's impossible to share it with someone. OP is asking for how to solve this requirement not if the requirement is correct.

Comment: @Ccm you told everything that was on my mouth! Thanks.

Comment: @achhainsan if you check if a phone-number is in use when people try register with you, you introduce a security leak: bad actors can use that feature to check whether someone with a particular phone-number is registered with you.

Comment: @achhainsan: I think what's confusing here is that you wrote *"Now, we get two customers with same mobile number."*. From your other comments, I suspect what you really meant is *"Now, we get the same customer twice in the system"*. May I suggest you edit the question and clarify this?

Comment: @PieterB what's achieved by testing if a phone numbered is registered with you? And what alternative do you suggest?

Comment: @Ccm, I'm not aware of any bank that assumes an iron link between a phone number on record, and a specific individual. We're not disputing the statistics - we're making the point that in any significant statistical set, you're going to get duplicates, either because the owner of the number has changed over time (and it's the existing record that needs correction, not the prohibition of making the new record), or because of unusual circumstances which lead to phones being communal property amongst a small number of people. A banking app is installed on a device, not a phone number.

Comment: the question is unclear. If you just want to enforce uniqueness in the db. use a unique constraint on the table. If you want to design a business process to prevent reuse of a mobile number. Just check to see if its already on your system in step 3? Whats the real question here, "how do i enforce uniqueness in a distributed database?"?

Comment: @Steve A banking app is actually stored _for a user_. I have seen apps working hard to identify the device I was using, and then I sold it and got a new phone. Old phone changed its phone number, new phone got my old number, but I stopped playing one game because my high score disappeared when I sold my phone.

Comment: @Ewan, the question should be "how do I handle real life and not make assumptions?" On some website an employee of a large insurance reported that they had two customers with the same last name, same first name, same address, and same date of birth. (It was a married couple, husband and wife, so the same last name and address. The identical date of birth is a one in two thousand coincidence. The same first name because they were both named Alex, or Sam, or Robin, or something like that).

Comment: @gnasher729 I dunno, I think phone numbers are tied to users for apps and its really a question about stopping this duplicate signup, rather than enforcing uniqueness

Comment: @PhilipKendall can you explain how you'd solve this problem using unique index?

Comment: @achhainsan `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foobar ON customers(mobile_number);` Now you can never have two customers with the same number, because the database will reject it. Obviously, you have to deal with that failure at the business level but there's no way round that.

Answer (score 7):

Mobile numbers are not guaranteed to be unique identifiers, and there is not even such a contrived example necessary to find a scenerio where the same mobile phone number belongs to two persons. This isn't restricted to scenarios where the number is redistributed, the same number can actually be in use by two persons **at the same point in time**. For example,  think about two family members where one of them does the bank registration for both using the same phone.

Hence, **automatically merging two accounts with the same mobile phone number is not an option**!

Of course, when the two user records are completely identical, same phone number / address / date of birth, and at least one of them hasn't got any money transactions associated so far, it may be possible to delete one of the accounts automatically.

But in all other cases, the best thing you can do here is to spill out a warning for the user during registering, or a warning for the bank operator who has to approve a phone number change, so they know the number is already in use. But there should always be an option to ignore the warning and let the staff manually validate user accounts with duplicate phone numbers (for example, by calling the number back and asking the person directly).

Comment: No two users can login with same username from different devices constraint is being applied accordingly already.

Comment: @achhainsan: Your comment is a bit of a non-sequitur, unless you are revealing here that the phone number is being used as the user's username? That brings with it a boatload of assumptions that aren't present in the question. Regardless, the same concerns that this answer raises remain valid - be very, very sure that you're intentionally excluding anyone who doesn't have a personal phone number that they manage themselves. Old people are usually quite important to banks, but are also prime targets for not managing their own phone numbers.

Comment: @achhainsan: *"No two users can login with same username from different devices"* - so what? Even if you meant "mobile phone devices" (I am not sure if you meant this), what is hindering two users to log in one after another, sharing the same device? Your user DB will still contain two registered users with the same mobile number,

Comment: Device id is associated. That's the l ast hint I can give.

Comment: @achhainsan: I have no idea what you are talking about,

Answer (score 3):

This question is about business process, not engineering. There is no design pattern, architecture, or coding technique that fixes a situation like this. Others have brought up valid points that mobile numbers cannot be guaranteed to identify a single human being at any moment in time, and over a span of time they certainly cannot identify a single human. How many times have you gotten a call from a stranger on your mobile phone, and upon answering, they ask you if "X" is there, only for the both of you to determine that "X" got a new phone, and you got "X's" old phone number.

Real life is messy.

You will need to consult with other people about how to handle this situation given the real world constraints with mobile numbers, multiple registration methods, and the fact these two registration methods can happen independently and concurrently by one person, or multiple people.

Answer (score 1):

From the moment that a registration is pending, self-registered or through the back-end, that phone number should become assumed to be in-use.

This means that from that moment on - whether the registration is completed or not - no other registration for that number can be started until the first one is cancelled.

In your given scenario, the user should not be able to self-register - though how to message the user around this is tricky, because you don't want to allow a malicious party to simply spam self-registrations to see when error messages occur, to find live phone numbers.

You can flag that the user attempted to self-register that number so that the bank processing the back-end attempt can communicate through the user on a different established channel.

In your scenario specifically, I would considerer architecting it like this:

1. The user is already registered with the bank, and therefore has a guaranteed unique user ID, and a mobile phone number A, registered.
2. The user requests to change their mobile phone number to B.  In order to perform this request, the user must go through certain steps to identify themselves, so the bank knows their unique user ID
3. The user's record is now flagged with a "change pending approval" flag, to change phone number A to phone number B.  Requests to the user's record still return phone number A.  At some point, a bank employee must process the "change pending approval" for approval or denial, but this hasn't happened yet.
4. The user attempts a self-registration request using phone number B.  They *still* have to perform identification steps so that the bank knows that it's the same user as in 1.  The bank receives the self-registration requests but sees that the account for this user is already flagged as "change pending approval".  They can verify at this point that the self-registration request has the same new number as the pending manual request (the expected situation), or a different number (which might trigger possible fraud/hacking steps).  However, in either case, the self-registration request is immediately *denied*, with possibly an additional flag added to the user's record that they attempted self-registration but it was denied because a change was pending.  In any case, there is only *one* change pending.
5. At some point, a bank employee handles the manual pending request and either approves or denies.  There's no issue with other pending changes in the DB.

Comment: Can you tell how my idea will fail? I can't think of it as per now.

Comment: @achhainsan I think it may be a phrasing issue: I'm not saying that in your existing scenario the self-registration will fail, I'm saying you should change the architecture so that it does.

Comment: I am not getting what you're trying to say. English isn't my first languge.